# How can I publish a specific subset of artifacts in Gradle

Tags: gradle

Hi I've inherited a project which is very poorly strung together. Its using gradle but still using uploadArchives. Its current artificat definition is something like this

```
artifacts {

if (someCondition) {
    {
        archives archive1
    }
    
if (someOtherCondition) {
        archives archive2
    }
```

I'd like to switch to ivy/maven publishing, i'm using ivy for now as I have a small bit of experience(minimal) with it on other gradle projects.

This project has a number of problems but I'd like to be able to say have tasks called publishArchive1 or publishArchive2 that a build can call specifically. Maybe I am searching the wrong terms but I cant figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [Maven Publish](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin.

You can create a single *publication*, then conditionally add artifacts to that publication which should align with what you have provided in the sample.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            // Configure other options here
            // ...
            if (someCondition) {
                from(someTaskWithOutputs)
            }
            if (someCondition) {
                from(someOtherTaskWithOutputs)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call `./gradlew publish` which will publish to **all** defined repositories. See the linked guide for more details

Answer (score 1):

In a typical turn of events once I decided to post a question I found my answer in a way.
Though I perhaps poorly phrased my question I was unaware that for each publication block defined gradle creates a tasks to publish just that one.

For reference this guide described it https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_setup.html#publishing_overview

in particular this excerpt

> In combination with the project’s group and version, the publication and repository >definitions provide everything that Gradle needs to publish the project’s production JAR. >Gradle will then create a dedicated publishMyLibraryPublicationToMyRepoRepository task >that does just that. Its name is based on the template >publishPubNamePublicationToRepoNameRepository. See the appropriate publishing plugin’s >documentation for more details on the nature of this task and any other tasks that may be >available to you.

This detail was missing from the gradle ivy publishng plugin documentation I was looking at before.